# Python pandas display dataframe as a table with tabs and not spaces

Tags: python, pandas, printing

How can I print or display a `pandas.DataFrame` object like a "real" table? I mean using **only one tab** between columns and **not more spaces**. In IPython Jupyter Notebook I can use the following code to get a "real" table style:

```
from IPython.core.display import display
display(df.head(50))
```

instead of `print(df.head(50))` which uses spaces.
Is there any same in IPython console using Spyder? I did no find a proper `pd.set_option()` value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Jupyter Notebook is a specialized environment, which knows how to tell objects to render themselves as HTML inside the Jupyter (web) interface. I don't believe Spyder has this capability.